(V2) Do these revisions to this "Survivalist" homebrew fighter martial archetype bring it in line with the existing subclasses?
This adventure I found on DMsGuild seems like it would be fun to play, and it comes with several character options. One in particular, the Survivalist Martial Archetype, seems like something I'd like to play in a different game, as a player. Is this fighter subclass balanced compared to the existing official ones?

[V1]: Original posting.
[V2]: Nerfs applied to (hopefully) balance the subclass. Fluff truncated.

Keep Moving
Starting at 3rd level, you are steady and consistent over long
distances and suffer less from the strains of both travel and
combat. You ignore any detrimental effects of difficult terrain,
you have advantage on Constitution saving throws, and when
you take a long rest, you require only half the normal amount
of time you would otherwise need.

Unchanged from original.

Padded Armor Master
Starting at 3rd level, when you wear padded armor, your AC
is 14 plus your Constitution modifier, you have resistance to
cold and fire damage, and padded armour doesn't give you
disadvantage on your Dexterity (Stealth) checks.

AC down to 14 + Con (from 16 + Con)

Let Me Catch My Breath
Starting at 7th level, when you spend hit dice to heal yourself, you regain the maximum amount possible from each die. Additionally, you can spend two hit dice to take a short rest over the course of a minute, rather than the usual time required. You do not gain hit points from the hit dice you spend to use this feature, but you can immediately spend additional hit dice to heal yourself.

Short rest requires 1 minute rather than 1 action.

Sure Footing
Starting at 10th level, when you wear padded armour, your AC
is 16 plus your Constitution modifier. Additionally, you have
advantage on Strength and Dexterity saving throws, plus
advantage on saving throws and ability checks to avoid being
knocked prone or to avoid or escape from a grapple.

AC nerfed to 16 + Con, from 18 + Con.

Extra Padding
Starting at 15th level, while you're wearing padded armor,
any critical hit against you becomes a normal hit, and you
have resistance to acid and lightning damage.

Swapped fire & cold immunity for acid & lightning resistance.

Survivor
Starting at 18th level, at the start of each of your turns in
combat, you regain hit points equal to 5 + your Constitution
modifier (minimum of 1 hit point). You don’t gain this benefit
if you have 0 hit points or if you have more than half of your
hit points left.

Unchanged from original. Also note that this is the same as the Champion fighter's capstone.

I changed the class per Eric's answer to the first iteration of my question.
I'd also like to know if the following changes improve the balance:

AC at 10th level is 15 + Con
AC at 15th level is 16 + Con


What happens if you change your paddled armor for paddled armor +1/2/3? That feature is IMO unsalvageable.
